# What is the right way to round the suggestBaseFee value from Etherscan Gas Tracker API?

Tags: transactions, gas, etherscan, gas-price, explorer-api

We are currently trying to calculate the correct priority gas value in GWEI as displayed on the Gas Tracker page on Etherscan using this API: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasoracle

In order to do that you need to subsctract suggestBaseFee from any of the three gas values, which are safe, propose, and fast. However, I can't manage to understand the way this suggestBaseFee should be rounded. My developer tried Math.round() and several other ways, but it gives wrong values anyway, not the ones that are displayed on Etherscan.

Does anyone have a better idea? Thanks a lot!